# Twilio post to url with params[:text_response] and params[:phone_number]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am using ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.

I am sending a text message out via my rails app to my end user.

When they respond, I want to redirect them to an api call:

`www.myapp.com/api/verify_text_response`

Within that API call, I want to see what the text message sent from the end user to my url is. Ideally, I would receive a param of "`text_response`" that I could then do what I wanted to with.

How can I redirect a reply from my end_user to the above url, and capture the phone number it came from as well as the message sent to me in my params? If this isn't possible, how can I use TwiML to do something similar?

## End Goal

For what it's worth, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. I send a text message out - "`Would you like to subscribe?`"
2. The end user responds "`Yes`" or "`No`".
3. I change the `subscribed` attribute on my `subscription` model to true or false.
4. I send another text message saying either "`You are subscribed.`" or "`You are not subscribed.`".

Item's #3 and #4 are based on the user responding "Yes" or "No" in item #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twilio guide [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/hello-monkey) for Ruby is the most useful documentation out there. They recommend using the Twilio gem in your Rails application by adding the `twilio-ruby` gem to your Gemfile.

All you need to do to is add the following code to one of your controller's actions (the one that is routed to by `www.myapp.com/api/verify_text_response`:

```
def receive_text
  # Not exactly sure this is the right parameter, but it's easy to test
  sender_message = params[:Body]

  response = if (sender_message == "Yes")
    "You are subscribed."
  else
    "You are not subscribed."
  end

  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Message(response)
  end
  twiml.text
end
```

To make your Rails application accessible to Twilio, follow the directions found on [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/hello-monkey):

> Copy and paste the URL of your server into the "SMS" URL of a number
>   on the Numbers page of your Twilio Account. On the page for that
>   number, change the Method from "POST" to "GET".

I wasn't exactly sure from looking at the documentation which parameter holds the user's response (I thought it was probably `params[:Body]`), but the best way to figure out is simply by printing out the parameters that the controller receives when you send a text message to your Twilio number.